# IIS URL Rewrite to correct an bad url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a bad url coming in as

```
http:/example.com/path/file.html how
```

How can I fix it to be

```
http://example.com/path/file.html how
```

Notice the `http:\` to `http:\\`

I don't want to fix it for just a single url, would like to be fixed for all urls that happen to have an error IIS URL Rewrite.

I coded many URL Rewrites before, but for some reason I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, there might be a better way, but this seems to fix the issue.

```
<rule name="Fix Slash Issue" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(http.?:\\[a-zA-Z0-9])" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https:\\{HTTP_HOST}\{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```